# Signing/Generating SSL Certificates for ElasticSearch (search-guard)

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, elasticsearch, wildcard, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to build my own ElasticSearch cluster and I decided to use an open source plugin called [Search Guard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/). It requires generation of client and host/node certificates. In its demo there is a script which generates a root ca, client and node certificates signed with the generated root ca.

My problem is that I want to use my wildcard ssl certificate for this. How can I create client and node certificates with my wildcard ssl certificate?

This is their [demo page](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-ssl-docs/blob/master/certificates.md) explaining how to generate the certificates, but I unfortunately couldn't manage it.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a wildcard cert, follow the same procedure but add a wildcard to the CN -- so instead of CN=foo.example.com, use CN=*.example.com.

Comment: You got me wrong. I already have a wildcard SSL certificate but I understood that it is not possible to sign a new client or node certificate with a domain certificate, which is my wildcard certificate. A root certificate or intermediate certificate is required for this.